# Why does this list return identical values?

Tags: python, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I'm trying to scrape http://www.virginiaequestrian.com/main.cfm?action=greenpages&GPType=8 for all of it's table values and putting the values in a list of lists. For some reason i can't seem to understand. Appending the info dict to the data list only puts in the one value 364 times(the length of the table). I printed each line and value separately in the loop and i know i am grabbing the right elements/value, but everything seems to break down when i try to put the values in the data list.

Can somebody please tell me when i'm doing wrong?

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests

r=requests.get('http://www.virginiaequestrian.com/main.cfm?action=greenpages&GPType=8')
soup=BeautifulSoup(r.content,'html5lib')

data = []
info = {}

tbl = soup.findAll('table')[2]
for tr in tbl.findAll('tr')[3:]:
    for td in tr.findAll('td')[0]:
        value= td.string
        info['Name']=value
    for td in tr.findAll('td')[1]:
        value= td.string
        info['City']=value
    for td in tr.findAll('td')[2]:
        value= td.string
        info['Phone']=value
    for td in tr.findAll('td')[3]:
        value = "http://www.virginiaequestrian.com/{}".format(td.a['href'])
        info['ListURL']=value
        data.append(info)
print data
```

Comment: You're filling `data` with *hundreds of references to the exact same dictionary*...

Comment: Yeah i got that. I was asking to try and figure out what i can do to fix it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Objects in python (like your `info` dict) uses references to their underlying data structures. What you are basicaly doing when calling `data.append(info)` is appending the same reference to the same dict over and over again.

What you can do is either (re)create your `info` dict at each iteration of the outmost for-loop:

```
for tr in tbl.findAll('tr')[3:]:
    info = {}
    ...
```

or append a copy of your dict into your list:

```
data.append(info.copy())
```

creating a new object each time.

---

You can also simplify your inner for-loops as iterating over one value is not really necessary:

```
for td in tr.findAll('td')[0]:
    value= td.string
    info['Name']=value
for td in tr.findAll('td')[1]:
    value= td.string
    info['City']=value
for td in tr.findAll('td')[2]:
    value= td.string
    info['Phone']=value
for td in tr.findAll('td')[3]:
    value = "http://www.virginiaequestrian.com/{}".format(td.a['href'])
    info['ListURL']=value
```

can become

```
name, city, phone, url = tr.findAll('td')[:4]
info['Name'] = name.string
info['City'] = city.string
info['Phone'] = phone.string
info['ListURL'] = "http://www.virginiaequestrian.com/{}".format(url.a['href'])
```

Comment: ...immutable objects like tuples and integers *also* use references to their underlying data structures; *all* names in Python are references.

Comment: You’re right, I was trying to phrase something else but got two explanations mixed up. Better ?

Comment: @Mathias Ettinger i ended up getting this error when i tried to run your second brik of code 
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "DadFile.py", line 12, in <module>
    Name,city,phone,url in tr.findAll('td')[:4]
NameError: name 'Name' is not defined

Comment: it’s `name, city, phone, url = ...` not `name, city, phone, url in ...`